# EOFError: Ran out of input

Tags: python, pickle

When I run the code below I get this error message "EOFError: Ran out of input"
what does it mean?? How it can be corrected?? and how to output the records details on the screen.

```
import pickle # this library is required to create binary files
class CarRecord:
    def __init__(self):
      self.VehicleID = " "          
      self.Registration = " "
      self.DateOfRegistration = " "
      self.EngineSize = 0           
      self.PurchasePrice = 0.00

ThisCar = CarRecord()
Car = [ThisCar for i in range(2)] # list of 2 car records

Car[0].VehicleID = "CD333"
Car[0].Registration = "17888"
Car[0].DateOfRegistration = "18/2/2017"
Car[0].EngineSize = 2500
Car[0].PurchasePrice = 22000.00

Car[1].VehicleID = "AB123"
Car[1].Registration = "16988"
Car[1].DateOfRegistration = "19/2/2017"
Car[1].EngineSize = 2500
Car[1].PurchasePrice = 20000.00

CarFile = open ('Cars.TXT', 'wb' ) # open file for binary write
for j in range (2): # loop for each array element
    pickle.dump (Car[j], CarFile) # write a whole record to the binary file
CarFile.close() # close file

CarFile = open ('Cars.TXT','rb') # open file for binary read
Car = [] # start with empty list
while True: #check for end of file
    Car.append(pickle.load(CarFile)) # append record from file to end of list
CarFile.close()
```

Comment: the code fails in the `while True` loops because when it gets to the end of the data it is trying to do another process on data that it doesnt have

Comment: try to pickle/unpickle your `Car` list directly

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer:** The simplest solution is to write the complete list to file using `pickle.dump()`. There's no need to write all objects one by one in a loop. Pickle is designed to do this for you.

**Example code and alternative solutions:**

Below is a fully working example. Some notes:

- I've updated your `__init__` function a bit to make the initialization code a lot easier and shorter.
- I've also added a `__repr__` function. This could be used to print the record details to screen, which you also asked. (Note that you could also implement a `__str__` function, but I chose to implement `__repr__` for this example).
- This code example uses standard Python coding styles (PEP-8).
- This code uses a context manager to open the file. This is safer and avoid the need to manually close the file.

If you really want to write the objects manually, for whatever reason, there are a few alternatives to do that safely. I'll explain them after this code example:

```py
import pickle


class CarRecord:

    def __init__(self, vehicle_id, registration, registration_date, engine_size, purchase_price):
        self.vehicle_id = vehicle_id
        self.registration = registration
        self.registration_date = registration_date
        self.engine_size = engine_size
        self.purchase_price = purchase_price

    def __repr__(self):
        return "CarRecord(%r, %r, %r, %r, %r)" % (self.vehicle_id, self.registration,
                                                  self.registration_date, self.engine_size,
                                                  self.purchase_price)


def main():
    cars = [
        CarRecord("CD333", "17888", "18/2/2017", 2500, 22000.00),
        CarRecord("AB123", "16988", "19/2/2017", 2500, 20000.00),
    ]

    # Write cars to file.
    with open('Cars.TXT', 'wb') as car_file:
        pickle.dump(cars, car_file)

    # Read cars from file.
    with open('Cars.TXT', 'rb') as car_file:
        cars = pickle.load(car_file)

    # Print cars.
    for car in cars:
        print(car)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
CarRecord('CD333', '17888', '18/2/2017', 2500, 22000.0)
CarRecord('AB123', '16988', '19/2/2017', 2500, 20000.0)
```

Instead of dumping the list at once, you ***could*** also do it in a loop. The following code snippets are alternative implementations to "Write cars to file" and "Read cars from file".

**Alternative 1: write number of objects to file**

At the start of the file, write the number of cars. This can be used to read the same amount of cars from the file.

```py
    # Write cars to file.
    with open('Cars.TXT', 'wb') as car_file:
        pickle.dump(len(cars), car_file)
        for car in cars:
            pickle.dump(car, car_file)

    # Read cars from file.
    with open('Cars.TXT', 'rb') as car_file:
        num_cars = pickle.load(car_file)
        cars = [pickle.load(car_file) for _ in range(num_cars)]
```

**Alternative 2: use an "end" marker**

At the end of the file, write some recognizable value, for example `None`. When reading this object can be used to detect the end of file.

```py
    # Write cars to file.
    with open('Cars.TXT', 'wb') as car_file:
        for car in cars:
            pickle.dump(car, car_file)
        pickle.dump(None, car_file)

    # Read cars from file.
    with open('Cars.TXT', 'rb') as car_file:
        cars = []
        while True:
            car = pickle.load(car_file)
            if car is None:
                break
            cars.append(car)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change you `while` loop to this:

this will `break` out of your `while` loop at the end of the input when it recieves the `EOFError`

```
while True: #check for end of file
    try:
        Car.append(pickle.load(CarFile)) # append record from file to end of list
    except EOFError:
        break
CarFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You get that error when the file you are trying to load with **pickle** is empty.So make sure that there's things written into **'.pkl file'**